# The Icons on the TabBarItems looks way too small on Android.

Tags: android, tabs

I have the icon supposed much bigger than what's shows up on tabbarItems. I don't why it shows up so small.

Main.XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/emptylayout1" android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
          <TextView android:id="@+id/textview2"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:text="Details Details Details Details"/>
      </FrameLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

MainActivity

```
     host=getTabHost();

       host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Offers")
            .setIndicator("Offers", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_light))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Offer_Popup.class)));

       host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Account")
            .setIndicator("Account", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_wrench))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Offer_Popup.class)));

       host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Settings")
            .setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_user))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Offer_Popup.class)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason could be using a icon designed for a low-density (usually 24x24) on a high-density screen (like 48x48). You can find more information on sizes and icon design on this web page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html
                                                                                                         Accept this answer please if it helped you solve your problem ;)

Good Luck-Lijap